# org.apache.tika.Tika return wrong or null mime type for multipart file

Tags: java, file-upload, mime-types, multipart, apache-tika

In my application I have file upload facility where users can upload any type of files. On the server I have to find the mime type and extension for the uploaded file. I have used different method for finding the mime type but each have some kind of limitation.

Case 1 :

```
public @ResponseBody String uploadActvityFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    try{
    String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(new File(file.getOriginalFilename()).toPath());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        jsonDept = "Failed";
    }
```

}

The above method finds mime type in most of the cases but return Null pointer exception when I upload an audio file with '.m4a' as extension.

Case 2 :

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
String mimeType = tika.detect(file.getBytes());
```

Above method returns a mime type in all cases, but it returns wrong mime type in most of the cases.

For eg :

Returns 'application/ogg' for '.opus' audio file.

Returns 'audio/mpeg' for '.mp3' audio file.

Returns 'video/3gpp' for '.m4a' audio file

Case 3 :

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
String mimeType = tika.detect(new File(file.getOriginalFilename()));
```

Case 4 :

```
Magic magic = new Magic();
MagicMatch match = magic.getMagicMatch(new File(file.getOriginalFilename()), false);
String mimeType = match.getMimeType();
```

Case 3 & 4 returns exception for all files of any kind as below :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Voice 002.m4a (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

What is wrong with all these methods. How can I extract the mime type correctly?

Comment: Assuming you have both the uploaded contents and the suggested filename, try a Tika facade detect method that takes both eg https://tika.apache.org/2.2.1/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-

Comment: @Gagravarr Can u show an example

Comment: I have no idea what your `File` object is, but just try one of the methods which takes both contents and a filename string, whatever seems closest to your actual data